# How to get a "perfect " Y-axis for hist(nclass=nclass.scott)?

Tags: r, histogram, scale

Occasionally `hist(..., nclass=nclass.scott)` produces a histogram where the maximum bar extends over the top of the y axis. You may try this example a few times:

```
x <- sample(1000000, 500, replace=TRUE)
h <- hist(x,nclass=nclass.scott)
text(x=h$mids, y=h$counts, labels=h$counts, pos=3, col="red")
```

Example:[image]

Occasionally the red number over the highest bar cannot be presented as it seems to be clipped by the plot region. I could add `ylim=...`, but it's quite tricky to get the maximum height of the bar.

Even when knowing the maximum height, `ylim=(0, max)` has the problem that `max` may be ignored: For example, when maximum is 527, then the upper displayed y-axis label is 500, even if `ylim=(0, 527)` is specified. When using `600` instead, it works, but then the y-axis is a bit too long...

If that is not a bug of R (3.3.3), what is an elegant (minimalistic) solution?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to set `par(xpd= T)` in your graph to avoid the trimming.

```
?par
```

> xpd
>
> A logical value or NA. If FALSE, all plotting is clipped to the
>   plot region, if TRUE, all plotting is clipped to the figure region,
>   and if NA, all plotting is clipped to the device region. See also
>   clip.

You can do it better by collaborating with `usr` option and `xpd`.Upon observation the bars seems going out of chart but it is not the bars that are  going outside the chart but the axis being restricted to the labels. Hence to fix the labels we can choose to use `usr`. In case someone wants to play with the margin, one can also use `mar`.

```
library(RColorBrewer)
par(mfrow=c(1,1),xpd=T,yaxs="i")
x <- sample(1000000, 500, replace=TRUE)
h <- hist(x,nclass=nclass.scott,axes=FALSE,col=brewer.pal(10,"Set3"))
# usr <- par("usr")
at <- c(0, 10,30, par("usr")[4])
axis(2,at=at,labels = round(at))
text(x=h$mids, y=h$counts, labels=h$counts, pos=3, col="red")
```

> usr
>
> A vector of the form c(x1, x2, y1, y2) giving the extremes of the
>   user coordinates of the plotting region. When a logarithmic scale is
>   in use (i.e., par("xlog") is true, see below), then the x-limits will
>   be 10 ^ par("usr")[1:2]. Similarly for the y-axis.

You may want to run it several times, I have run it for many times, the bar won't seems to go outside the chart now.

**Output**:

[image]

Comment: The little nuggets of helpfulness within `par` never cease to amaze me

Comment: The actual problem was the bar exceeding the axis; clipping is just the secondary effect. I'd like to see a fix for the primary effect.

Comment: @U.Windl see my edit. I hope this fixes your problem

Comment: @PKumar: Your "solution" adds many new features I don't actually want (e.g. logarithmic scale, colored bars, etc.), and I don't really see what part of your "solution" really fixes my problem. Setting `par("usr")[4]` might solve the problem, but you don't do that, right?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is not a bug. You are using functionality to draw a histogram and then you want to add text to it. The function has not been designed for that, hence you need to reserve some additional white space for the text.

I suggest you run the function once, to get the "base values" of the graph. Then run the function again with adjusted scale (extra space for the text). In order to achieve this, you could use the following code

```
set.seed(9876)         ### for reproducibility

x <- sample(1000000, 500, replace = TRUE)
h <- hist(x, nclass = nclass.scott, plot = FALSE)

### use the info from the previous call to adjust the y-scale with a constant
hist(x, nclass = nclass.scott, ylim = c(0, max(h$counts) + 10))
text(x = h$mids, y = h$counts, labels = h$counts, pos = 3, col = "red")

### ... or add a proportion (a little bit more robust)
hist(x, nclass = nclass.scott, ylim = c(0, max(h$counts) * 1.075))
text(x = h$mids, y = h$counts, labels = h$counts, pos = 3, col = "red")
```

Please let me know whether this is what you want.

Comment: Wouldn't that create a plot two times, first wrong, then right?

Comment: @U.Windl. The idea is to store histogram information in `h` first (and we don't plot to the screen). Then, we use the information in `h` to plot the graph for real. I mistakenly assigned the histogram info to h again the second time. I will update my answer now.

Comment: I still don't get why the first invocation does not create a plot: Shouldn't you have added `plot=FALSE` to the first call of `hist()`?

Comment: Finally, can we get rid of the magic `10` in `ylim = c(0, max(h$counts)+ 10)`?

Comment: Evidently, we could use a proportion of the maximum height (h$counts) that we add to provide white space for the text we want to add. I updated my answer with this possibility.

Comment: It's all terrible: So we replaced the magic `+ 10` with magic `* 1.075`. Where does the `1.075` come from? Trial and error? I'd really wish R would work more like Gnuplot that simply does what I say, i.e. if I say `ylim=c(0, 100)` the y axis should extend from `0` to `100` (and not a bit less, maybe).

Comment: On _"The function has not been designed for that, hence you need to reserve some additional white space for the text."_: The problem is _"Occasionally hist(..., nclass=nclass.scott) produces a histogram where the maximum bar extends over the top of the y axis."_. The effect that text above the bars may be clipped for the highest bars is a secondary effect.